# How to print the final version of `docker-compose.yml` with .env variables replaced?

Tags: docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which uses a few variables set in an `.env` file.

Is there an easy way to print the final version of the file, to check if everything was correctly replaced?

```
# .env
UBUNTU_VERSION=19.8
```

.

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  myservice:
    image: ubuntu:${UBUNTU_VERSION}
    env-file:
      - .env
```

**Note:**

> Compose supports declaring default environment variables in an
> environment file named .env placed in the folder where the
> docker-compose

Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following files:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    image: ubuntu:${UBUNTU_VERSION}
    env-file:
      - .env
```

```
# .env

UBUNTU_VERSION=20.01
```

You can run

```sh
docker-compose config
```

And you'll get the formatted config file out:

```
❯ docker-compose config
services:
  myservice:
    environment:
      UBUNTU_VERSION: '19.8'
    image: ubuntu:19.8
version: '3'
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my question was clear enough. I update the question with more details. Seems I was not thinking of it the same you are.

Comment: @RobertoMorávia I updated based on your feedback, I think this should do what you need

Comment: That's it. Thanks! My Google-fu needs improving.

Comment: The env-file key is misspelled, it should be env_file. And you don't need to specify it if you name the variables in your compose file. Compose reads that automatically. The env_file key is for passing an arbitrary file with env variables to the container on startup so that they are available inside the container without naming them in the compose file.